# How to programmatically stop reading from stdin?

Tags: c, pthreads, stdin, eof

fgetc() and other input functions can return when there's no data on the file descriptor. This can be simulated for console applications reading from stdin typing Ctrl-D on keyboard (at least on unix). But how to do it programmatically? For example, how to return from the fgetc() in the reader thread in the following code (NB: ignore the possible race condition)?

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void* reader()
{
    char read_char;
    while((read_char = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        ;
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, reader, NULL);

    // Do something so the fgetc in the reader thread will return

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you simply want to `close()` the other end of the pipe but you example doesn't really make sense as the main thread doesn't control the other end of stdin.

Comment: I tried this weeks ago but I didn't find any mean of knowing the other end of stdin. Any other way to achieve the same goal? Maybe I am missing something: I just need a way to not block threads on console input.

Comment: The other end of stdin is typically the keyboard of your terminal. Perhaps what you need is non-blocking I/O? It's hard to tell from your question. You should explain what you are trying to do in more details.

Comment: No, I don't need non-blocking I/O. Not in the sense I should poll for input with timeouts with select() or poll() at least: this would be wronger than trying to close the terminal keyboard device. It seems to me I was getting the wrong point trying to access stdin from different threads. This is probably wrong and I should avoid this by keeping a state of my application in the scope of the input "reader" so I can easily track when input should be processed or not.

Comment: Incidentally, the Windows equivalent to UNIX's control-D is control-Z.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you want a threads to stop blocking on `fgetc(stdin)` when some event occurs to handle that event instead. If that's the case you could `select()` on both `stdin` and some other message pipe so that the thread can handle input from both:

```
fd_set descriptor_set
FD_ZERO(&descriptor_set); 
FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &descriptor_set); 
FD_SET(pipefd, &descriptor_set); 

if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &descriptor_set, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) 
{ 
  // select() error
} 

if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &descriptor_set)) {
  // read byte from stdin
  read(STDIN_FILENO, &c, 1);
}

if (FD_ISSET(pipefd, &descriptor_set)) 
  // Special event. Do something else
```

Also note that only one thread in your process should be reading from `stdin`.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly the answer to my question, super thanks! It may be overkill in my real needs but anyway this is THE way go if someone need a similar pattern. I was near this solution when I tried this weeks ago but I completely missed the ability of select() to track more than one file descriptor. In my previous comment about not using select() or poll() I was against using timeouts but it seems you perfectly got the point. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can either 'close' standard input, or connect standard input to '/dev/null' ('NUL:' on Windows) with `freopen()`, or you can connect standard input to '/dev/zero'.

If you close it, every function call will fail because the file stream is not valid.  If you connect it to the null data source, all reads will fail and return EOF immediately.  If you connect it to the zero data source, every read will succeed and return a corresponding number of zero bytes.

It is possible one of those will suit your needs sufficiently.  If not, then you probably need to give us a more detailed explanation of what you actually need.

Comment: I tried this without success some time ago but does not seems portable and in fact it doesn't work on linux. Trying to close stdin (or any other file descriptor) while fgetc() is waiting for data does block here. Got discussed here: http://lkml.indiana.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/0106.0/0768.html with reference to select() and reply from linux devs was: "undefined behavior".

Comment: @ceztko: closing standard input in one thread while another thread is reading - yes, that is not going to be reliable...I must have misread the question.

Answer (score 1):

Alexandre posted the correct solution. His answer respond precisely to the question I asked. It follows simple self compiling code based on his hints:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/select.h>

static int pipe_fds[2];

void* user_interaction()
{
    char read_char;
    
    fd_set descriptor_set;
    FD_ZERO(&descriptor_set); 
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &descriptor_set); 
    FD_SET(pipe_fds[0], &descriptor_set);

    while(1)
    {
        if (select(FD_SETSIZE, &descriptor_set, NULL, NULL, NULL) < 0) {
            // select() error
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &descriptor_set)) {
            // read byte from stdin
            read(STDIN_FILENO, &read_char, 1);
            // Re-set the selected file descriptor so it can
            // be signaled again
            FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &descriptor_set);
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(pipe_fds[0], &descriptor_set))
            // Special event. break
            break;
    }
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    pipe(pipe_fds);
    
    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, user_interaction, NULL);
    
    // Before closing write pipe endpoint you are supposed
    // to do something useful
    sleep(5);

    close(pipe_fds[1]);
    
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);
    
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With POSIX you can signal the thread whose primitives (e.g. "read") are blocking, and if you have set up a do-nothing signal handler with the SA_RESTART bit cleared then the primitives will fail with EINTR errors. Here's a working version of the original:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

static void SignalHandler(int signum)
{
}

void* reader(void *arg)
{
    char read_char;
    while((read_char = fgetc(stdin)) != EOF) {
        ;
    }
    printf("leaving reader\n");
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    struct sigaction action;
    memset(&action, 0, sizeof(action));  // SA_RESTART bit not set
    action.sa_handler = SignalHandler;
    sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

    pthread_t thread;
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, reader, NULL);

    sleep(1); // time to start reader thread
    // Do something so the fgetc in the reader thread will return
    pthread_kill(thread, SIGUSR1);
    sleep(1); // time to exit reader thread; could join it if set up

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I haven't tested but I guess your code will work. Still, I think your approach is a bit coarse: you signal a thread and, depending of the complexity of the `reader()` function, you can cause unintended exit points that were not necessarily intended, because of side-effects in large code area (kernel primitives) you have no control. I think the approach suggested in the marked answer is much more fine grained and allow to precisely preempt thread on intended exit point. See also my answer with the complete example.

Comment: @ceztko: Yes, my approach is simpler but much less targeted. I'm unclear on a point with the marked answer: Can you use it with higher level functions like fscanf?

Comment: Apparently you can use `fscanf` with pipe, with some [caveats](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43349557/213871)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to use the code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4186321/12255999) in a slightly modified form:

```c
void *user_interaction()
{
    char ch;
    int rv;
    fd_set set;

    FD_ZERO(&set);
    FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &set);
    FD_SET(pipe_fds[0], &set);

    while (1)
    {
        rv = select(pipe_fds[0] + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (rv < 0)
        {
            printf(">>> select(): error occurred, %d\n", rv);
            break;
        }
        
        if (FD_ISSET(pipe_fds[0], &set))
        {
            printf(">>> pipe_fds[0]: is ready\n");
            break;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &set))
        {
            read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &ch, 1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

but wasn't getting the expected behaviour. When executed like in the below:
`$ echo -n 1 | ./a.out`

my terminal was being rendered with `1`'s in the infinite loop and the pipe was never reported by `select()` to be ready (i.e. even after `close()`ing it in the main thread).

With some experimentation, I figured that you need to move `FD_ZERO`/`FD_SET` inside the loop, to get `select()` to work as desired:

```c
void *user_interaction()
{
    char ch;
    int rv;
    fd_set set;

    while (1)
    {
        FD_ZERO(&set);
        FD_SET(STDIN_FILENO, &set);
        FD_SET(pipe_fds[0], &set);

        rv = select(pipe_fds[0] + 1, &set, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if (rv < 0)
        {
            printf(">>> select(): error occurred, %d\n", rv);
            break;
        }
        
        if (FD_ISSET(pipe_fds[0], &set))
        {
            printf(">>> pipe_fds[0]: is ready\n");
            break;
        }

        if (FD_ISSET(STDIN_FILENO, &set))
        {
            read(STDIN_FILENO, &ch, 1);
            write(STDOUT_FILENO, &ch, 1);
        }
    }

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Comment: Simplify your answer by trimming away code that doesn't work and keep only the good part. Also you could comment the original answer and pointing what was wrong. In that FD_ZERO is not strictly necessary but re-setting the signaled descriptor is. I will fix in my answer for the user data descriptor (the other descriptor is for control/quit the program).

Comment: Wanted to comment but my "reputation" here was to low... :(

Glad you like the improvements!