# Why fprintf and fscanf does not work with pipe

Tags: c, unix

I have written the program which creates pipe, write a number to pipe, read it from pipe and print it to stdout. But it seems to be that fscanf see empty pipe stream, although I made fflush.

Why fprintf does not print anything?

```
int main() {
    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);

    FILE* write_file = fdopen(fd[1], "w");
    FILE* read_file = fdopen(fd[0], "r");
    int x = 0;
    fprintf(write_file, "%d", 100);
    fflush(write_file);
    fscanf(read_file, "%d", &x);

    printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to *close* the writing end of the pipe, not only flush it. Otherwise the `fscanf()` doesn't know, if there is still data to read (more digits):

```
fprintf(write_file, "%d", 100);
fclose(write_file);
fscanf(read_file, "%d", &x);
```

Alternatively, write a blank after the digits to make `fscanf()` stop looking for more digits:

```
fprintf(write_file, "%d ", 100);
fflush(write_file);
fscanf(read_file, "%d", &x);
```

This should both fix your issue.

Comment: @Ctx That helped! Thank :)

Answer (score 2):

`fscanf(read_file,"%d")` reads from the stream as long as it retrieves something that matches the pattern`"%d"`, i.e. as long as no white space, non-digit, etc character is read, `fscanf` "waits" until the next character comes in.

Hence, `fprintf(write_file, "%d\n", 100);` will solve the problem, because it "terminates" the number written to the pipe, such that the subsequent `fscanf` will be terminated, too.